# Как из многомерного массива удалить массив у которого нет ключа?

Tags: php

Есть массив вида:

```
Array (
[7] => Array ( [639] => 639 [678] => 678 [679] => 679 [680] => 680 [716] => 716 [786] => 786 )
[21] => Array ( [639] => 639 [802] => 802 )
=> Array ( [639] => 639 )
[9] => Array ( [646] => 646 [693] => 693 [740] => 740 [751] => 751 [765] => 765 )
[22] => Array ( [646] => 646 [707] => 707 [708] => 708 [709] => 709 [710] => 710 [711] => 711 [712] => 712 [725] => 725 [732] => 732 [762] => 762 )
=> Array ( [646] => 646 )
)
```

3 и 6 элементы без ключа. Как можно их удалить?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: var_dump выводи, и увидишь истинные ключи

Comment: скорее всего там или пустой ключ или пробел, или несколько пробелов.

Comment: как может быть элемент массива без ключа? Если массив основан на том, что у него всегда есть ключ при наличии значения

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо! получил истинную картину. Почему-то неправильно обработались входные данные, буду ковырять